# Python ImportError: No module named 'convert.py'

Tags: python, importerror

I tried searching the site for similar problems, but none seemed to have my exact dilemma.

For a tutorial book on Python, I wrote a program that converts Celsius temperatures to Fahrenheit. When I run it in the IDLE shell, the program works, but returns an error. Here is the code for the program itself:

```
#convert.py
#converts Celsius temperatures to Farenheit

        def main():
            celsius = input("Type the temperature in degrees Celsius: ")
            farenheit = ((9/5)* int(celsius)) +  32
            print(farenheit)

    main();
```

And here's the error.

```
>>> import convert.py
Type the temperature in degrees Celsius: 59
138.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import convert.py
ImportError: No module named 'convert.py'; 'convert' is not a package
```

I am using Python 3.4.1.

Comment: Without the `.py`, and you don't need `;` either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not add the file extension when importing a Python module.  You should do:

```
>>> import convert
```

This code:

```
>>> import convert.py
```

is telling Python to import the nonexistent `py` module that is located in the `convert` package.

Here is a [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) on importing modules and packages in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop the `.py` extension; Python imports use just the base name:

```
import convert
```

What happens is that Python imported `convert`, *then looks for a nested module named `py`*. That part fails, because `convert` is not a package and cannot contain another module.